# How do I reference a remote file path from git hub?

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, jquery-plugins, remote-access

I am not getting the location of url.

Example: cookie.js or iframeResizer.js

I do not want to download these files. I want to refer to these files through remote(GitHub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **github**, browser a code, find a needed file, click it, on the top right you will find **Raw** button. Press it and copy **URL** from browser. But better to find some **CDN** instead of include resources in such way.